# Thermocouple K Type using a jack plug instead of the normal connector

Tags: thermocouple

I have a few thermocouple K Type using the classic two lead connector.

[image]

I would like to change that connector to a male jack type like this:

[image]

So I can connect it to the female connector that has waterproof cap:

[image]

The problem is that the jack connector lacks of screws as the original yellow one. Is it possible to solder the leads to the jack plug terminals? Any advice on how to do it please.

Thanks

Comment: While the answers below are correct, you should also interpret them correctly. I.e. **None of the below matters**, and you can use any connector you want as long as your solder/crimp junction in the additional connector is at the same temperature as the voltmeter. The special connectors make this very likely because they move the junction literally *into* the voltmeter. It only matters if your connector could be at a different temperature than the voltmeter, e.g. if you can touch it.

Comment: Can you tolerate a less accurate thermometer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful what metals you use in the current path. Any change in alloy will create a voltage that can be thermally sensitive.  Connectors are typically the same material as the wires all the way up to the sense circuitry.  Here is an example of positive and negative terminal metals used in the connectors for each color of the common double-spade thermocouple connector.

[image]

Comment: It's not so much 'be careful what you use', it's only use K-type metals unless you can tolerate the consequences or know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @VAAA GT tells it like it is. ***Any*** change in metal creates another thermocouple. (Copper isn't all the same, for example, as manufacturers have different grades and mixes they use while still calling all of it "copper.") It can be a minor change, with only a small change to the gradient, or it can be large. But every time you connect two dissimilar metals, you've got yet one more thermocouple to deal with. If any solder wets in between? Then you've got two more thermocouples. Don't forget that different points far apart may be at different temps, too. It is all very, very annoying.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR You can do what you want to do, but probably should not**

Yes. I have successfully soldered K-type wires, using a very aggressive flux-cored solder that's intended for soldering aluminium. I've done this to solder thermocouple tips to solder tags, for easy attaching to a heatsink.

Pro tip. It's probably better to 'tin' the thermocouple wires using the nasty stuff first. This allows you to clean off the flux easily, and check that the solder has indeed wetted the wires. Then complete the joint to the connector with normal solder.

You do realise that putting all these uncontrolled intermediate junctions into your thermocouple path is going to introduce errors of possibly many degrees, not necessarily bounded by the uncertainty in connector temperature. If your accuracy requirement is low, you may be able to live with this.

Alternatively, if you take steps to ensure all the connectors are at the same temperature (enclose them, avoid thermal gradients through them, ignore readings for the first hour or so after connection while they come to thermal equilibrium) then you can still get accurate readings. Make sure that you use K-type wire back from the connector to your thermometer electronics. If you use copper, then you've shifted the cold junction to the front panel, and you're really in trouble for accuracy.

Using the proper K metal connectors avoids all of that trouble, just connect and go.

Why do you want to replace the proper connectors with random metal jacks? The proper connectors don't take up much more panel space that the jacks you suggest. However, they are more expensive. They are not more expensive simply because they are the right shape. You are paying for the fact that they continue the K-type thermocouple metals right through the connector. Thermally, electrically, it's as if they were not connectors, but a continuation of the thermocouple wire.

Comment: You are right, this might affect the readings. Maybe I will have to stay with the yellow connectors to avoid any issue on the readings right?

Comment: You can solder them but you can't make the right kind of junction.  You need to weld them to do that.

Comment: @KyleB As long as you keep the entire multi-metal junction at a uniform temperature, you can make one and still have the correct thermocouple behaviour. The problem is keeping the entire set of metal-to-metal junctions at the same temperature. So soldering the wires of a tip together is generally OK. Running the wires through non-K-type plugs is generally not OK, not because of the foreign metals *per se*, but because of the difficulty of getting each junction the same temperature. What generates the TC voltage is the temperature gradient in each of the K metals, not the junctions themselves.

Answer (score 0):

A type K thermocouple uses wires made of chromel and alumel, neither of which are wettable by any solder I'm aware of. So no, you can't solder it.